# Não consigo realizar POST, PUT E DELETE de uma chave primária UUID. Somente o GET

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, post, uuid

No meu projeto, não consigo obter as requisições POST, PUT E DELETE de uma chave primária UUID, pois retorna erro 405.
Somente consigo listar todos os dados. Estou usando o PostgresSql e o data.sql está em código binário.
Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "equipment")
public class Equipment implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "equipment_model_id")
    private EquipmentModel equipmentModel;

    public Equipment() {
    }

    public Equipment(EquipmentModel equipmentModel, UUID id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public EquipmentModel getEquipmentModel() {
        return equipmentModel;
    }

    public void setEquipmentModel(EquipmentModel equipmentModel) {
        this.equipmentModel = equipmentModel;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Equipment other = (Equipment) obj;
        return Objects.equals(id, other.id);
    }

}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/equipments")
public class EquipmentResource {

    @Autowired
    private EquipmentService service;

    @ApiOperation(value="Lista todos os equipamentos")
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<EquipmentDTO>> findAll() {
        List<Equipment> list = service.findAll();
        List<EquipmentDTO> listDto = list.stream().map(x -> new EquipmentDTO(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(listDto);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Lista os equipamentos por id")
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<EquipmentDTO> findById(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        EquipmentDTO dto = service.findById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(dto);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Cria os equipamentos")
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<EquipmentDTO> insert(@Valid @RequestParam EquipmentDTO dto) {
        dto = service.insert(dto);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(dto);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Atualiza os equipamentos")
    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<EquipmentDTO> update(@Valid @RequestParam UUID id, @Valid @RequestBody EquipmentDTO dto) {
        dto = service.update(id, dto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(dto);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Deleta os equipamentos")
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        service.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class EquipmentService {

    @Autowired
    private EquipmentRepository repository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Equipment> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public EquipmentDTO findById(UUID id) {
        Optional<Equipment> obj = repository.findById(id);
        Equipment entity = obj.orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Entity not found"));
        return new EquipmentDTO(entity);
    }

    @Transactional
    public EquipmentDTO insert(EquipmentDTO dto) {
        Equipment entity = new Equipment();
        copyDtoToEntity(dto, entity);
        entity = repository.save(entity);
        return new EquipmentDTO(entity);
    }

    @Transactional
    public EquipmentDTO update(UUID id, EquipmentDTO dto) {
        try {
            Equipment entity = repository.getReferenceById(id);
            copyDtoToEntity(dto, entity);
            entity = repository.save(entity);
            return new EquipmentDTO(entity);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Id not found " + id);
        }
    }

    public void delete(UUID id) {
        try {
            repository.deleteById(id);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Id not found " + id);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException("Integrity violation");
        }
    }

    private void copyDtoToEntity(EquipmentDTO dto, Equipment entity) {

        entity.setId(dto.getId());
        entity.setName(dto.getName());
        entity.setEquipmentModel(dto.getEquipmentModel());

    }
}
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/equipment
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123456

spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=operation
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Answer (score 0):

405 geralmente ocorren quando vc esta chamando um endpoint com o metodo errado. Por exemplo chamando via POST um metodo GET.

Vi seu print e vc esta tentando mandar id como path param no POST, depois do **/equipament/{AQUI}**

Acredito que o problema é que no seu metodo **@PostMapping** precisa ser declarado o path param **"/{id}"**, tipo assim **@PostMapping("/{id}")** igual fez nos outros. Tambem vai precisar adicionar mais um parametro no metodo **insert** para receber o id, ficaria algo assim:

```
@ApiOperation(value="Cria os equipamentos")
@PostMapping('/{id}')
public ResponseEntity<EquipmentDTO> insert(@Valid @RequestParam EquipmentDTO dto, @PathVariable UUID id) {
    dto = service.insert(dto);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(dto);
}
```

Provavelmente estava dando 405 pq sua chamada não estava de acordo com a assinatura do endpoint POST e sim do GET ou um dos outros endpoints q vc criou

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela resposta. Fiz o procedimento do seu jeito e agora retorna 400 bad Request.